# Is there a way to create a tomcat session manually?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Is there a way to create a tomcat session manually?

I'm working on a system where a web service will give the authentication credentials and I need to authenticate the request and send the session id as the response if the credentials are correct.

I'm using [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) as my application framework and [spring ws](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/) for web service implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean create)
```

By default, if you use this method, a session will be created if one doesn't already exist. Use `getSession(false)` if you don't want to create one if you're sure one doesn't exist.